# change round slider color depending on value

Tags: javascript, round-slider

I am trying to let the range color change from green to red when people move the slider from 100 to 0. I use JS Round slider (https://roundsliderui.com/document.html).

MRE is here: https://codepen.io/chapkovski/pen/gORmrbR
But it looks like that:

```js
$("#slider1").roundSlider({
    sliderType: "min-range",
    value: 80,
      // svgMode: true,
    valueChange: "changeColor",
});
function componentToHex(c) {
  var hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}


var sliderObj = $("#slider1").data("roundSlider");
function changeColor(e) {
    const val = e.value * 2.55;
      sliderObj.rangeColor = rgbToHex(255 - val, val, 0);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt in this way you will be able to change color. You can only change color if there is a setter exposed for rangeColor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your demo there are few problems, so you may have to correct the below things:

1. You are setting the property value in a wrong way. To update any property value dynamically, you can follow any of the below syntax:

```
$("#slider1").roundSlider("option", "rangeColor", rgbToHex(255 - val, val, 0));

OR

$("#slider1").roundSlider({"rangeColor": rgbToHex(255 - val, val, 0) });

OR

sliderObj.option("rangeColor", rgbToHex(255 - val, val, 0));
```

https://roundsliderui.com/document.html#how-to-use-options

2. In the color code generation logic you are doing something like this `e.value * 2.55`, but this will return the floating value. But hex color code won't accept the float value. So make this value round.

```
Math.round(e.value * 2.55)
```

3. You have commented the `svgMode: true`, it should be enabled.

And one more suggestion, you can upgrade to the v1.6.1 for better improvement.

### Here is the modified DEMO which works fine:

#### https://codepen.io/soundar24/pen/mdwWBzX